# Dictionary Test-First

Tags: ruby

Can someone tell me what keywords method does? I had to look up why my code wasn't working and saw that someone had that method, so I added it and it works. I know it sorts, but what else does it do

```
class Dictionary

  attr_accessor :entries

  def initialize
    @entries = {}
  end

  def add(x, value = nil)
    if x.is_a?(Hash)
      x.each do |key, value|
        @entries[key] = value
      end
    else
      @entries[x] = nil
    end
  end

  def keywords
    @entries.keys.sort
  end

  def include?(x)
    @entries.keys.include?(x) ? true : false
  end

  def find(x)
    answer = {}
    @entries.each do |key, value|
      if key.include?(x)
        answer[key] = value
      end
    end
    answer
  end

  def printable
    final = @entries.sort.map {|key, value| "[#{key}] \"#{value}\""}
    final.join("\n")
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It takes out the keys of the hash `@entries`, and return them as an array sorted. It does not have any side effects.

Comment: Thanks. I am writing based on Rspec expectations and I kept failing one test. I just didn't know what it was actually doing.